# Rack::Lock#call too much time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, nginx, puma

Newrelic says `Rack::Lock#call` takes around 9 sec.

Please see below Snapshot:

http://prntscr.com/ay7ccx

We have following server configuration

- Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit
- Puma with 2 worker, 1 to 6 max threads
- Nginx as frontend
- Rails 4 and Ruby 2
- 7 GB RAM and 4 core cpu

Can any one help that why it takes so much time in middleware?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like rails' multithreaded mode is off. This adds the `Rack::Lock` middleware which in turn uses a mutex to ensure each rails instance handles one request at a time. The numbers you are seeing show that this is causing requests to queue inside your rails instance.

This is controller by the `allow_concurency` setting, which defaults to false.

As a side note, MRI isn't good at concurency (if you are cpu bound) - you may be better off running more workers with fewer threads. You could also switch to jruby (which doesn't have a GIL) but that is obviously a bigger undertaking.

Comment: 2 worker and 6 threads will be enough if i enable `allow_concurrency` to true ?

Comment: That depends entirely on your application, the load it is under and whether you are CPU bound or not.