# How to run Rails multi-threaded in development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on a multiple projects that talk to each other sometimes and I've run into an issue where app

1. A calls B (`request 1`, still running)
2. B calls A (`request 2`)
3. based on `request 2`'s result, B responds to request 1

This requires me running multi-threaded rails in development mode.

I know I can set it up using puma or something like that but ... Isn't there really a simpler way?

I would like to avoid changing anything in the project (adding gems, config files..).

Something like `rails s --multi` would be nice, can't `webrick` just run with multiple threads or spawn more processes?

Can I perhaps install a standalone gem to do what I need and run something like `thin run . -p 3`?

Answer (score 12):

The [puma](https://github.com/puma/puma) web server can provide multi-threading and multiple workers bound to a single local address.

1. Install the puma gem:

   ```
   bundle add puma
   ```

   or

   ```
   gem install puma
   ```
2. Add a puma configuration file at `config/puma.rb`:

   ```
   workers 1 # 1 worker in addition to master instance (i.e. handle 2 requests concurrently).
   preload_app!
   ```
3. Launch the Rails server.

   ```
   bundle exec rails s
   ```

   *Puma automatically starts and loads in the config file at `config/puma.rb`.*

Bump up the value for `workers` if you need to handle more than 2 concurrent requests at the same time.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: And with Rails 5, Puma should be the default server so for those using it, the problem I describe becomes non-existent.

Comment: Be aware of Rack::Lock#call. Depending on your Rails version if rails' multithreaded mode is off Rack::Lock will serialize all your requests independently of the number of threads. See more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932334/racklockcall-too-much-time

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve this is to use [POW](https://github.com/basecamp/pow), which uses two workers by default.

The nice thing is I don't have to modify the project files to do it so it satisfies my requirements.

**Update**: The up to day successor of POW is [puma-dev](https://github.com/puma/puma-dev), which is also zero-configuration.

Comment: Is it still relevant? the link is dead...

Comment: basecamp repo still exists so I updated it to it, likely outdated solution

Comment: Puma-dev is the emotional successor to pow. It provides a quick and easy way to manage apps in development on macOS and Linux. => https://github.com/puma/puma-dev

Answer (score 1):

My current solution, that's super kludgy, is to use [Foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman) and a Procfile to run two copies of my app on different ports. You'd have to configure your B service to make requests to the secondary port.